How to determine the alpha value of artificial viscosity in smoothed particle hydrodynamics?
I am confused about how to choose an appropriate value of $\alpha$ in the artificial viscosity. The value that I deduced is far from the recommended value and led to great numerical instability.
Artificial viscosity is introduced into the momentum equation of smoothed particle hydrodynamics:
$$
\Pi_{ij}=-\alpha h\frac{c_i+c_j}{\rho_i+\rho_j}\frac{\boldsymbol{v}_{ij}\cdot\boldsymbol{r}_{ij}}{{r_{ij}}^2+\epsilon h^2},
$$
where $\alpha$ is a dimensionless factor, $h$ is SPH kernel radius and $c$ is the speed of sound. The artificial viscosity is related to the physical dynamic viscosity (Pa*s) by
$$
\mu=\frac{\rho\alpha hc}{8}
$$
for two-dimensional cases (1). Hence, if the values of $h$, $c$ and $\mu$ are given, we can estimate the value of $\alpha$ as
$$
\alpha=\frac{8\mu}{\rho hc}.
$$
When it comes to the sound of speed, in order to both limit the density variation within 1% ($\delta\rho/\rho\sim v^2/c^2$) and allow an acceptable timestep (by the CFL condition), $c$ is also artificial, and customary to be $10v_\mathrm{max}$, where $v_\mathrm{max}$ is the maximal fluid velocity (2,3). As to the case of dam break with the initial water column height of $H_0$, the estimate of $v_\mathrm{max}$ is
$$
v_\mathrm{max}=\sqrt{2gH_0}.
$$
So Monaghan set $c$ as $\sqrt{200gH_0}$ in (2).
Assume the initial spacing between fluid particles is $H_0/N$, and the SPH kernel radius is triple the spacing,
$$
h=3\frac{H_0}{N}.
$$
Now we may obtain a proper value of $\alpha$:
$$
\alpha=\frac{8\mu}{\rho\cdot(3H_0/N)\cdot 10\sqrt{2gH_0}}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{15}\frac{\mu N}{\rho\sqrt{gH_0^3}}
$$
In the case of dam break, one can assume that $\mu=1\times 10^{-3}~\mathrm{Pa\cdot s}$ (water), $\rho=1000~\mathrm{kg/m^3}$, $100\leq N\leq 1000$, $0.1~\mathrm{m}\leq H_0 \leq 1~\mathrm{m}$, $g=9.81~\mathrm{m/s^2}$, and we may estimate that
$$
6\times10^{-6}\leq\alpha\leq2\times10^{-3}.
$$
This is way too far from the recommended range of $\alpha$ which is 0.01-1.
And when I used the estimated alpha value to simulate the dam break, it could not converge as expected. So, I wonder whether there is any mistake in my estimation, or any misunderstanding of the SPH theory. Any comments or advice will be appreciated!
=========================
Happy to know that the question is reopened. These days I tested different speeds of sound ($c_0$) with Morris's laminar viscosity model (4), and was surprised to observe that $c_0$ lower than $10v_\mathrm{max}$ can lead to a more stable pressure field!
N.B. To ensure the laminar flow, $H_0$ was set as 0.002 m such that Reynolds number=396. Other parameters are:
$\Delta L=3\times10^{-5}~\mathrm{m}, ~h=1.5\Delta L,~\Delta t=0.2h/c_0$.
$c_0$ is set to be 10, 5, 2.5 and 1.5 times of $v_\mathrm{max}$.
I compared the SPH results with those obtained by COMSOL two-phase laminar flow:

COMSOL showed that the velocity is between 0-0.18 m/s and the pressure difference is about 9 Pa. Lowering the speed of sound did not alter the velocity field significantly, but did stabilize the pressure field. This is really astonishing. It seems that $\delta\rho/\rho$ did not decrease as quickly as $v^2/c_0^2$. For example, when $c_0=1.5v_\mathrm{max}$, it showed that $\delta\rho/\rho=0.133$ while $v^2/c_0^2=0.36$.
References

Monaghan, J. J. Smoothed particle hydrodynamics. Rep. Prog. Phys. 68, 1703–1759 (2005).

Monaghan, J. J. Simulating Free Surface Flows with SPH. Journal of Computational Physics 110, 399–406 (1994).

Monaghan, J. J. Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamics and Its Diverse Applications. Annual Review of Fluid Mechanics 44, 323–346 (2012).

Morris, J. P., Fox, P. J. & Zhu, Y. Modeling low Reynolds number incompressible flows using SPH. Journal of Computational Physics 136, 214–226 (1997).



I don't see how this question is engineering, it's a discussion on the meaning of a term in a numerical algorithm which should be on-topic here, voting to re-open.

@KyleKanos Thanks a million!

Please don't use rainbow plots, they mask the information you're trying to show (so as to effectively provide no information). There are better options available.

I have changed rainbow to viridis.

This isn't my area of expertise, but as far as I know, $\alpha$ is a fudge factor and shouldn't be treated as (or tied to) a physical parameter.
For instance, if you tried tying it to the Reynolds number using a dam break with $U=L=1$, $c=10$, $h=0.0025$ and $\alpha=1$, then
$$Re_\text{SPH}=\frac{\rho UL}{\mu}\approx\frac{8UL}{\alpha hc}=320$$
and even if you decreased $\alpha\to0.01$, then you still get $Re_\text{SPH}\sim10^{4}$. But for the real Reynolds number for the dam break is order a million ($\rho\sim10^{3}$, $\mu\sim10^{-3}$).

Besides $\rho$ and $\mu$, the characteristic length $L$ also counts. $U\propto\sqrt{L}$ and $h$ as the particle spacing, is also proportional to $L$.

Last I checked, $\sqrt{1}=1$ and $h=0.0025\implies N=400$ particles in the unit square. You could alternatively increase $N$ to say $10^6$ ($h\sim1e-6$) to get yourself into the correct Reynolds number. In either event, I don't think this changes that $\alpha$ is not a physical parameter but a fudge factor to make it work right (this is at least how I've seen it described in most books/papers, including one of the Monaghan papers you've identified).

$N$ can theoretically be 10^6, but will lead to ~10^12 particles for 2D problems and thus add to much more unnecessary computation consumption. So I specified N between 100 to 1000.

$N$ can be any tractable number you want (and 400 is within the range of 100 to 1000), but I feel that your focusing on the numerical values of these parameters that you're missing the point that $\alpha$ isn't a physical parameter, just a numerically-verified parameter that makes the simulation behave properly.
